# How to remove an object from array of tuples

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

I learn Swift and I find very limited functionality of Arrays really annoying.

Consider the following array of tuples:

```
var points = Array<(touch: UITouch, startPoint: CGPoint)>()
```

Is there a painless way to remove a particular object from that array?

The closest thing is `removeAtIndex` method, though I can't figure out how to get an index of my tuple!

I tried this, but it doesn't seem working for tuples, as they are not equatable:

```
self.points.removeAtIndex(Int(find(self.points, point)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a way to do it:

```
let point1 = (touch: UITouch(), startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
let point2 = (touch: UITouch(), startPoint: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))

var points: [(touch: UITouch, startPoint: CGPoint)] = []    
points += [point1, point2]

// delete point2
points = points.filter { !($0.touch == point2.touch && $0.startPoint == point2.startPoint) }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you abandon the tuples and use your own struct like so:

```
struct TouchPoint: Equatable {
    var touch: UITouch
    var startPoint: CGPoint

    init(touch: UITouch, startPoint: CGPoint) {
        self.touch = touch
        self.startPoint = startPoint
    }

}
```

Define `==` for your `TouchPoint` type to satisfy the `Equatable` protocol:

```
func ==(lhs: TouchPoint, rhs: TouchPoint) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.touch == rhs.touch) && (lhs.startPoint == rhs.startPoint)
}
```

Then you can use `TouchPoint` like this:

```
var arr = [TouchPoint]()

let tp1 = TouchPoint(touch: UITouch(), startPoint: CGPointMake(1, 2))
let tp2 = TouchPoint(touch: UITouch(), startPoint: CGPointMake(3, 4))

arr.append(tp1)
arr.append(tp2)
```

Since your `TouchPoint` type is `Equatable`, you can use `find` to find and remove your items:

```
if let index = find(arr, tp2) {
    arr.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Comment: You could also use `filter` instead of `find` and `removeAtIndex`: `arr = arr.filter { $0 != tp2 }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said, I'd like a painless solution :) Removing an object from an array is a pretty trivial task, and I am very surprised that Swift doesn't offer such functionality out of the box.

Comment: Yes. It's frustrating how difficult some things are to do when the language looks so much like Ruby.